# DISNAKE | Почему у меня не работает cooldown?

Tags: python, disnake

## У меня не работает КД в когах.

**Помогите пожалуйста как ее решить?**

Ошибка когда ввожу повторно команду /work (когда должно появится кд) мне пишет: **"Приложение не отвечает"** Бот включен и все вроде хорошо но когда выбивает ошибку консоль пуста.

Код **/work**:

```
@commands.slash_command(name='work', description='Работа')
@commands.cooldown(1, 30, commands.BucketType.user)
async def work(self, interaction):
    money = randint(100,500)
    await self.db.update_money(interaction.author,money,0)
    embed = disnake.Embed(title='Работа', description=f'Вы заработали {money} {ds.coin}')
    embed.set_footer(text=interaction.author.name, icon_url=interaction.author.avatar.url)
    embed.set_author(name=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar.url)
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Код на обработку ошибки (кд):

```
@work.error
async def work_error(self, error, interaction):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandOnCooldown):
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=disnake.Embed(title="Ошибка", description=f"Подождите ещё **{error.retry_after:.2f}**", ephemeral=True))
```